# How can I detect if __WARN__ handler was called as a result of an explicit warn()?

Tags: perl

I have a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler.   Is there a way to determine if that was called as a result of an explicit `warn` call vs. a warning generated by Perl (e.g. using an undefined variable)?

Comment: I have to wonder why you want to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to use a `__WARN__` handler as some kind of exception mechanism? Because there are much better ways to do that. Like exceptions.

Comment: By overriding `warn` (with `local $in_warn = 1; CORE::warn(@_);`).

Comment: I have an existing app that uses $SIG{__WARN__} to include a stack trace in the logs.   But don't need the stat trace for explicit warn() calls.   So, looking for an easy way to suppress without having to touch too much of the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is what is passed into the handler, as in

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $warning = shift;
    #do something with warning.
}
```